# Appending a variable to a list to create 10 rectangles

Tags: python

I'm trying to make my code have 10 randomly placed and sized rectangles appear all over the screen, but even with my loop I'm not getting the 10, only one. I'm pretty sure my issue is with the way I'm appending the stuff in my loop to my_list, but I'm not sure.

I know this is probably an easy fix, but I just can't figure it out, thanks for the help ahead of time.

```
import pygame
import random

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

class Rectangle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randrange (0, 700)
        self.y = random.randrange (0, 500)
        self.height = random.randrange (20, 70)
        self.width = random.randrange (20, 70)
        self.change_x = random.randrange (-3, 3)
        self.change_y = random.randrange (-3, 3)

def move(self):
        self.x += self.change_x
        self.y += self.change_y    

def draw(self, screen):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREEN, [self.x, self.y, self.height, self.width])


pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

my_list = []

for i in range(10):
    my_object = Rectangle()
    my_list.append(my_object)   


# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             done = True

    # --- Game logic should go here

    # --- Drawing code should go here

    # First, clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    my_object.move()
    my_object.draw(screen)

    # --- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Try writing in a print statement in the for loop, see what happens.  Also, it's good form to save the size of the screen as a global constant `SIZE = (700, 500)` before any other definitions and use that to create the `self.x`-and-`self.y`-initializing lines.  EDIT: Also, your Rectangle.move() and Rectangle.draw() are not in the Rectangle class.  Move it up just a tad, maybe that's the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You're only drawing one rectangle. This:

```
while not done:

    [..]

    # --- Drawing code should go here

    # First, clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    my_object.move()
    my_object.draw(screen)
```

Should be more like this:

```
while not done:

    [..]

    # --- Drawing code should go here

    # First, clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    for my_object in my_list:
        my_object.move()
        my_object.draw(screen)
```